# how to set ngmodel inside ngfor

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor

```
<div class="carousel-cell lw-pr-30" style="width: 220px;"  *ngFor="let item of product?.products; let i = index">
<div class="lw-w-auto lw-h-80p">
<div class="lw-ff-Ubuntu lw-fs-18"> $ {{item.price}}</div>
<div class="lw-fs-12 lw-ff-Ubuntu">{{item.name}}</div>
<div class="lw-fs-12 lw-ff-Ubuntu">1 Lbs</div>
      </div>

<mat-icon class="lw-ta-e " style="float: right;height: 40px;" *ngIf="!item.cart" (click)="addCart(names,item)" svgIcon="cartround"></mat-icon>
 <div class="lw-ta-e lw-d-flex lw-align-center" style="float: right;height: 40px;" *ngIf="item.cart">
 <mat-icon (click)="removeCounter(names,item)" svgIcon="minus"  class="lw-cursor-p"></mat-icon>
 <input type="text" class="count" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  [(ngModel)]="names" name = 'names' min="1" maxlength="2" max="20"  disabled/>
              <!-- ngModel #names="ngModel"   -->
  <mat-icon  (click)="addCounter(names,item)" svgIcon="plus"  class="lw-cursor-p"></mat-icon>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKWv4.png)

when i click on plus button all the input changes at a time.how to change the clicked button's input

Comment: Can you show an example of the values in names array and in specialList array and how they need to be matched? Here you are using the same array as a model for each element, that's why this array is always being modified

Comment: what is happening inside `addCounter` function ? show us your ts file also.

Comment: this.names = 1                                                                              
                                                              addCounter(input,item)
  {   
    this.names = this.names + 1                                                                                     
  }

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo.
try to change

```
(click)="..(*names*,item)"
```

to

```
(click)="..(*name*,item)"
```

if not try to use `index`

if possible please share `stackblitz` we can help.